# How do you set the font-size of the placeholder in polymer paper-input?

Tags: polymer

Tried setting the font-size style for the polymer paper-input element, but this only resizes the font of the input that is entered. It does not resize the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're explicitly using the [`<paper-input>.placeholder`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input#property-placeholder) property (e.g., `<paper-input label="Label" placeholder="Placeholder">`), the placeholder's font size matches the input text's font size, so it's configured with the [`--paper-input-container-input`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container#styling) custom property:

```
/* <paper-input class="big-placeholder" label="Label" placeholder="Placeholder"> */
.big-placeholder {
  --paper-input-container-input: {
    font-size: 40px;
  };
}
```

```html
<head>
      <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/components/">
      <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
      <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
    </head>
    <body>
      <x-foo></x-foo>

      <dom-module id="x-foo">
        <template>
          <style>
            .big-placeholder {
              --paper-input-container-input: {
                font-size: 40px;
              };
            }
          </style>
          <paper-input class="big-placeholder" label="Label" placeholder="Placeholder"></paper-input>
        </template>
        <script>
          HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
            Polymer({ is: 'x-foo' });
          });
        </script>
      </dom-module>
    </body>
```

If you're otherwise using [`<paper-input>.label`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input#property-label) alone (i.e., `<paper-input>.placeholder` is not set), the label also serves as the input's placeholder, so three custom properties are needed to get the desired effect:

- `--paper-input-container-label` to size the label
- `--paper-input-container-input` to size the input text to match the label's size
- `--paper-input-container` to expand the container to fit the larger font size of the inner input and label

```
/* <paper-input class="big-label" label="Label"> */
.big-label {
  --paper-input-container-label: {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 44px;
  };
  --paper-input-container-input: {
    font-size: 40px;
  };
  --paper-input-container: {
    line-height: 44px;
  };
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        .big-label {
          --paper-input-container-label: {
            font-size: 40px;
            line-height: 44px;
          };
          --paper-input-container-input: {
            font-size: 40px;
          };
          --paper-input-container: {
            line-height: 44px;
          };
        }
      </style>
      <paper-input class="big-label" label="Label as Placeholder"></paper-input>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
        Polymer({ is: 'x-foo' });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OXOrxb)

Comment: The above did change the font size of the text entered, but did not change the font-size of the placeholder.

Comment: However, thanks for the reply. It got me looking down the right path. The answer to my question was. 

`paper-input {
      --paper-input-container-label: {
              font-size: 10px;
       }
}`

Comment: this solution is not correct!! it will change both input and placeholder font size!!

Comment: Expanded answer to show how to style the label used as the placeholder when `<paper-input>.placeholder` is not set.